# If A, B, C, D are four points on a circle in order such that AB = CD, prove that AC = BD.

Tags: circles

If A, B, C, D are four points on a circle in order such that AB = CD. How do you prove that AC = BD.

Comment: Could you show us your efforts?

Comment: Te problem is I do not even know how to start with his problem. If I can be given a hint on how to start, I will try to figure this out..

Comment: It may or may not be useful here, but in general, if the quad has 4 points  on a circle, then the opposite angles always add up to 180°

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$AB=CD$ and $AO=BO=CO=DO=R \implies$
$\triangle AOB \cong \triangle COD \implies$
$\angle AOB = \angle COD$

$\angle AOC = \angle BOD$ and $AO=OC=OB=OD\implies$
$\triangle AOC =\triangle BOD \implies$
$AC=BD$

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of the arc $BC$. Then the  complete figure is symmetric with respect to the line $O\vee M$.